# org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getExecutable() Null Pointer Exception using java 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, java-17

curretly I'm working on upgrading the project to java 17 and for some reason I have an issue on my junit tests that it didn't happen when I used java 11:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Executable.toGenericString()" because the return value of "org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getExecutable()" is null
```

The junit test is about testing `MethodArgumentNotValidException` case

```
   @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
   private MethodParameter methodParameter;

   MethodArgumentNotValidException method = new MethodArgumentNotValidException(methodParameter,bindingResult);
```

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is Mockito upgraded as well? This has the hallmarks of code instrumentation going wrong.

Comment: Using `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` doesn't mean that you don't need to use `when(...).returns(...)`, it just means that you don't need to mock every call in a chain.

Comment: Anyone know the issue behind this? Running the test individually or in a class in IntelliJ doesn't trigger the error, but running the whole maven project (consisting of multiple maven modules) does trigger the issue, locally. In Jenkins, no trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code try to convert the methodParameter to a string in a logger or in printstacktrace for example, and the mock has implemented a return for this case.